# merge two temp tables and add common columns as new row and add unmatch column using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using ms sql server, i have two tables below( table 1 and table 2):

```
table 1                   table 2                   result
name value      ++       name  data ==            name  value  data
test  10                 test1  20                test   10     null
                                                  test1   null   20
```

I want to merge table 1 and table 2 and my expected result would be as result table , can anybody help me here ?

Comment: UNION ALL. Put null in the select lists' 3rd/2nd column.

Comment: thanks, but i need it dyamically, column name is not constant..

Answer (score 1):

```
-- start the merge statement 
MERGE
--identify the Target/destination table
#TempTable as X
--identify the Source/information table
USING #tempTableTwo as Y
--show it how to match up the two tables together.
on X.A = Y.A
-- put in logic to input a row if not in the source target already
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY X 
    THEN
        -- target table columns
        insert (A,b,c,d)
        -- values to put into the table
        values(x.a,Y.b,x.c,x.d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these using a full join:

```
select coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name, t1.value, t2.data
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.name = t2.name;
```

If you want to use `*` to select all columns in the tables, SQL Server does not offer simple way to choose unique columns (without listing all columns).  SQL Server doesn't support `USING`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but it's repeating 'name ' column 2 times, i want to combine the data of 'name' field as i have mentioned in my result table..

Comment: I know, it's not easy, that's why i posted this question to make it easy. looking answer of this if it's possible..